# What is the difference between Orientdb editions?

Tags: nosql, graph-databases, orientdb

I've been reading about OrientDB for a while now, and I'm a bit confused about the "Editions" of the software.

The main version sounds like it's just the document store, but things on the internet make it sound like it's both the document and graph database. http://nosql.mypopescu.com/post/1254869909/correction-orientdb-is-a-document-and-graph-store

What is the difference between that and the graph edition?
Does the graph edition just do graphing with nodes and edges, or is it the document graph database?

**Update:** What is the key value store version? How does it differ? Can you use alongside the other editions?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

[OrientDB](http://www.orientechnologies.com) is a document-graph dbms because has the document-db features but handles relationships using direct links, not with JOINS like RDBMS.

So you can use the standard version to map even a graph. The Graph Edition is the Standard one with bundled the [TinkerPop](http://www.tinkerpop.com/) technology stack like the Gremlin language.

Comment: What is the Key Value store edition? I updated the question above. I heard Aaron Patterson had been working on a nice ruby implementation of a client, but I was going to try working out a ruby client using the REST api.

Comment: Key Value edition is not more supported. We preferred to focus on the Document-Graph engine. However since OrientDB is very fast with indexes (it uses a new algorithm called MVRB-Tree) many users use OrientDB as key value engine, via HTTP or Binary protocol, creating a manual index: http://code.google.com/p/orient/wiki/OrientDB_REST#Index

Comment: that's really awesome. Thanks for the second answer.

Answer (score 1):

The current version of OrientDB (1.6.0) implements the Blueprints graph database API (previously it also had its own low-level db api). If you write your client code in a Rexster binding (such as Bulbs in Python), it should be easy to change to any other graph database engine later on

Key-value store mode is no more actively developed.